# Using Onsen UI with an ember app

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, handlebars.js, onsen-ui

I have built an app with Ember.js and Cordova which runs perfectly on newer devices, but is laggy on older devices.

Onsen UI works perfectly for my needs, however it is designed around Angular and I am not sure if it is even possible to implement it with Ember. (I have tried to no avail).

I have looked for using Ember and Angular together, however all I found was Angular vs. Ember debates.

The forum page of Onsen UI asks visitors to post on Stack Overflow.

I am looking for guidance on how to implement Onsen UI with Ember/Handlebars.

This is the particular demo I want to utilize http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/demo/sliding_menu/

Comment: as far as I'm aware they're rather mutually exclusive. Maybe you can borrow onsen's stylesheets and hope for the best, but it sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: I took your advice, but it was way too tied in with Angular.  In the end I wound doing it with a demo from hammer.js.   If you post that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Alright, i'll try to make it a little more substantial... feel free to edit later with more info if you like

Comment: Might be better if you posted your own solution instead. I'll remove mine in that case. You be the judge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember and Angular are mutually exclusive and should not (and probably cannot) be used together. There are parts of OnsenUI that can be reused like the stylesheets but it'll be a lot of work since Angular uses directives that can be styled too.